# Botframework V4: DateTimePrompt not getting result

Tags: c#, datetime, botframework, prompt

How can i get the result of a datetimeprompt in azure botframework v4?
This results in an error. I even tried the ones that are commented. Or is there a betterway to get a Birthday? Like a date time picker?

```
 public class GetNameAndAgeDialog : WaterfallDialog
    {
        public GetNameAndAgeDialog(string dialogId, IEnumerable<WaterfallStep> steps = null) 
            : base(dialogId, steps)
        {
            AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
            {
                return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
                   "datePrompt",
                   new PromptOptions
                   {
                       Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("When is your birthday?"),
                   },
                   cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            });

            AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
            {
                //  var bday = (stepContext.Result as DateTimeResolution).Value;
                // var bday = Convert.ToDateTime(stepContext.Result);

                var bday = (DateTime)stepContext.Result;
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync($"{bday}");

                return await stepContext.NextAsync();

            });
        }
}
```

Im adding the like this:

```
_dialogs.Add(new DateTimePrompt("datePrompt"));
```

And how can I validate this? I only need the date to compute the Age.

Answer (score 1):

The lack of strong typing in the dialog/prompt APIs unfortunately makes this very difficult to discover, but the result of a `DateTimePrompt` is actually an `IList<DateTimeResolution>`.

Comment: I managed to get it by "var bday = (stepContext.Result as IList<DateTimeResolution>)?.FirstOrDefault().Value;"

Answer (score 1):

This is something I use as a date time prompt. It uses the `Microsoft.Recognizers.Text.DataTypes.TimexExpression` library.

```
public class CustomDateTimePrompt : ComponentDialog
{
    public CustomDateTimePrompt(string dialogId)
        : base(dialogId)
    {
        WaterfallStep[] waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            InitializeAsync,
            ResultRecievedAsync
        };

        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog("customDateTimePromptWaterfall", waterfallSteps));
        AddDialog(new DateTimePrompt("datetime", ValidateDateTime));
    }

    private Task<DialogTurnResult> InitializeAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (stepContext.Options is PromptOptions options)
        {
            if (options.Prompt == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options.Prompt));
            }

            return stepContext.PromptAsync("datetime", options, cancellationToken);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Options must be prompt options");
        }
    }

    private Task<DialogTurnResult> ResultRecievedAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (stepContext.Result is IList<DateTimeResolution> datetimes)
        {
            DateTime time = TimexHelper.GetDateTime(datetimes.First().Timex);

            return stepContext.EndDialogAsync(time, cancellationToken);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Result is not datetimes");
        }
    }

    private Task<bool> ValidateDateTime(PromptValidatorContext<IList<DateTimeResolution>> promptContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IList<DateTimeResolution> results = promptContext.Recognized.Value;

        if (results != null)
        {
            results = results.Where(r => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Timex) && TimexHelper.IsDateTime(r.Timex)).ToList();

            return Task.FromResult(results.Count > 0);
        }
        else
        {
            return Task.FromResult(false);
        }
    }
}

public static class TimexHelper
{
    public static bool IsDateTime(string timex)
    {
        TimexProperty timexProperty = new TimexProperty(timex);
        return timexProperty.Types.Contains(Constants.TimexTypes.Date) || timexProperty.Types.Contains(Constants.TimexTypes.Time);
    }

    public static bool IsTimeRange(string timex)
    {
        TimexProperty timexProperty = new TimexProperty(timex);
        return timexProperty.Types.Contains(Constants.TimexTypes.TimeRange) || timexProperty.Types.Contains(Constants.TimexTypes.DateTimeRange);
    }

    public static DateTime GetDateTime(string timex)
    {
        TimexProperty timexProperty = new TimexProperty(timex);
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

        int year = timexProperty.Year ?? today.Year;
        int month = timexProperty.Month ?? today.Month;
        int day = timexProperty.DayOfMonth ?? today.Day;
        int hour = timexProperty.Hour ?? 0;
        int minute = timexProperty.Minute ?? 0;

        DateTime result;
        if (timexProperty.DayOfWeek.HasValue)
        {
            result = TimexDateHelpers.DateOfNextDay((DayOfWeek)timexProperty.DayOfWeek.Value, today);
            result = result.AddHours(hour);
            result = result.AddMinutes(minute);
        }
        else
        {
            result = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0);
            if (result < today)
            {
                result = result.AddYears(1);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this but i can't make it work. I'll just go for the simpler ones.